# AJAX time limit inside each loop for a PHP mail send function

Tags: php, jquery, email, pear, amazon-ses

I have built a fairly basic mailer that uses PEAR Mail and sends emails through Amazon SES to a relatively small (<100), list of people.

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
$('#mailer_final_form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#forms_wrap').slideUp();
    $('#sender').slideDown();
    var url = "/mailer?action=send";
    var totalEmailrec = $('.email-recipients').length;
    var totalEmailrecp = totalEmailrec+1;
    $('#total_togo').html(totalEmailrec);

    var totalSent = 1;

    $('.email-recipients').each(function(){
    var thisRecipient = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: url,
         data: $('#mailer_final_form').serialize()+'&recipient='+thisRecipient,
         success: function(data)
         {
            $('#total_sent').html(totalSent++);
            $('#return_values').append(data);
                if (totalSent==totalEmailrecp) {
                    $('#loader_image').fadeOut();
                    $('#return_values').append('<br><b>Finished!</b>');
                }
         }
     });

    });

});
```

Unfortunately, sometimes the mailer crashes and it doesn't tell me why, this is my PHP:

```
if ($_GET['action']=="send") {

    set_include_path('/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear');

    $mailer_from = $_POST['sender'];
    $mailer_subject = $_POST['email_subject'];
    $mailer_body = $_POST['email_body'];        
    $salutation_type = $_POST['salutation_type'];       
    $recipient = $_POST['recipient'];
    $recipient = explode('||',$recipient);
    $recipient_name = trim($recipient[0]);
    $recipient_email = trim($recipient[1]);

    if (filter_var($recipient_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

    define('USERNAME','my_ses_id');  
    define('PASSWORD','my_ses_pw');  
    define('HOST', 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com');  
    define('PORT', '587');     

    require_once 'Mail.php';

    define('SENDER', "$mailer_from");

    if (strpos($recipient_name, '@') !== false) {
    define('RECIPIENT', "$recipient_email");
    } else {
        define('RECIPIENT', "$recipient_name <$recipient_email>");
    }

    define('SUBJECT', "$mailer_subject");

    switch ($salutation_type) {
        case 1: // dear ***
            if (strpos($recipient_name, '@') !== false) {
                $salutation = "Dear recipient,<br><br>";
            } else {
                $salutation = "Dear $recipient_name,<br><br>";
            }
        break;
        case 2: // no salutation
        $salutation = "";
        break;
    }

    define('BODY',"
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>$mailer_subject</title>
    </head>
    <body style='background:#eee;padding:40px;width:100%;'>
    $mailer_template_header
    $salutation
    $mailer_body
    $mailer_template_footer
    </body>
    </html>");

    $headers = array ('MIME-Version'=>'1.0','Content-type'=>'text/html;charset=UTF-8','From' => SENDER,'To' => RECIPIENT,'Subject' => SUBJECT);
    $smtpParams = array ('debug' => false,'host' => HOST,'port' => PORT,'auth' => true,'username' => USERNAME, 'password' => PASSWORD);

    $mail = Mail::factory('smtp', $smtpParams);
    $mail->send(RECIPIENT, $headers, BODY); 

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) { "<span class='emails-sent'>$recipient_name ($recipient_email) -".$mail->getMessage()."</span><br>"; } else {
    echo "<span class='emails-sent'>$recipient_name ($recipient_email) - OK</span><br>";
    }

    } else { echo "<span class='emails-sent'>$recipient_name ($recipient_email) - INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS / NOT SENT</span><br>"; }
}
```

What I would like to do, is somehow prevent the mailer from crashing, and set some kind of timeout to skip any email attempts that don't want to work (or at least get the correct error showing as to why that one is failing).

I have tried tirelessly to do this with jQuery's setInterval and various timer loops, but this appears not to want to work within the primary each loop (executing mail AJAX call for each email address).

Could anyone kindly suggest a way (preferably with jQuery), to skip an email address with an "xyz failed due to a timeout" message on that particular address? Or perhaps show me within my PHP how I can time out with the same error being returned to the mailer's interface?

Comment: What about sending all the email addresses in JSON to the php, and have `php` loop through and do the dirty work.  That way you're only making a single `AJAX` call and thus reducing overhead significantly.  You'll be better able to handle the loop in php as far as timeout etc etc etc ..

Comment: Thanks Zak, are you suggesting something like serializing the addresses in a single AJAX call (dropping the 'each' loop), and then adding dataType:JSON to that call? If I do that, I'm still stuck with dodgy addresses... do you know how I could catch the errors or "skip" dodgy addresses on the PHP side?

Comment: Yes, I'd serialize everything and send 1 giant call.  `PHP` has a built in filter for `variables`  --> `filter_var()`   ...  Also inside of that filter you can sanitize and validate emails IE: `$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);` that serves most purposes for removing invalid characters etc etc. .. Then you can use `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`  IE `if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {`  --  Beyond that you'd have to `regex` for keywords etc etc.